# Rails 3 | Routing : How to rename resource title now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Generally I have MenuItems model and trying to make '/menu_items(/:id(:/some_action))' URLs looks like '/menu(/:id(:/some_action))'

In Rails 2.3.5 it was

`map.resources :menu_items, :as => :menu, :path_names => { :new => 'add' }`

Now in Rails 3.0.3 I'm able to handle it using this huge paragraph of code

```
  resources :menu_items, :path_names => { :new => 'add' }
  match 'menu/' => 'menu_items#index', :as => :menu
  match 'menu/add' => 'menu_items#new', :as => :new_menu
  match 'menu/:id' => 'menu_items#show', :as => :show_menu
  match 'menu/:id/edit' => 'menu_items#edit', :as => :edit_menu
```

But it looks incorrect because of huge amount of code.
Seems :as works like 2nd Rails' map.some_name now.

Any help/suggestions/guides? (Thanks)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes

```
resources :menu, :controller => "menu_items", :path_names => { :new => "add" }
```

Output is quite close to what you're after:

```
menu_index GET    /menu(.:format)             {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"index"}
           POST   /menu(.:format)             {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"create"}
  new_menu GET    /menu/add(.:format)         {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"new"}
 edit_menu GET    /menu/:id/edit(.:format)    {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"edit"}
      menu GET    /menu/:id(.:format)         {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"show"}
           PUT    /menu/:id(.:format)         {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"update"}
           DELETE /menu/:id(.:format)         {:controller=>"menu_items", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the as: name also for the new path name?

Answer (score 13):

Another way

```
resources :menu, :as => :menu_items, :controller => :menu_items
```

This approach has the advantage that the exiting helper methods such as menu_items_path still work.